# div hide and show inside PHP from checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have button click event in html page where I am calling a PHP file. inside the php I have two div where I want to show hide according to the check box I have ...
now it shows two check box and the show div. but i want load the show div only if user checks the first check box how can i achieve this? pls help.here the PHP Code

```
<div id="dialog_title">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="First">
    First List<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="Second">Second
</div>

    <div id="Show div">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Address </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach ( $deviceArr as $device) {
                $id = $device['id'];
                $name = $device ['name'];
                $Address = $device['address'];
                ?>
                <tr class="font1">
                    <td> <input type="text" class="g_input_text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /> </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="text" class="g_input_text" name="address[]" value="<?php echo $Address; ?>" /> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>


        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: How are you calling the php file with a form post or javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

When the page is loaded hide the `show div` i named `first_list_bx` and give an id as `first_chk_bx` to first check box like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="First" value="First" id="first_chk_bx">

<div id="first_list_bx" style="display:none;">
     //code
</div>
```

Then use jquery for detecting checkin of checkbox and show the `first_list_bx` like:

```
$('#first_chk_bx').click(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $("#first_list_bx").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#first_list_bx").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you expecting?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Show').hide();
    $("input[name=First]").click(function () {
        $('#Show').toggle();
    });
 });
```

It's done in [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). Find **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PmL7S/)**

Note: Change `<div id="Show div">` to `<div id="Show">`

Answer (score 0):

as you tagged your question with `javascript` try this js function in your html like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog_title">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="First" onclick="javascript:show_hide(this, 'Show_div')">
    First List<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="Second">Second
</div>

    <div id="Show_div" style="display:none">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Address </th>
            </tr>

                 <?php
        foreach ( $deviceArr as $device) {
            $id = $device['id'];
            $name = $device ['name'];
            $Address = $device['address'];
            ?>
            <tr class="font1">
                <td> <input type="text" class="g_input_text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /> </td>
                <td> 
                    <input type="text" class="g_input_text" name="address[]" value="<?php echo $Address; ?>" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>




        </table>

    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
        function show_hide(my_obj, id)
        {
            var chk = my_obj.checked;
            if(chk===true)
            {   
                document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```